# SpringSecurity UserDetailsService REST Client

Tags: spring-security, userdetailsservice

I'm using `SpringBoot 2.4.7` and I'm trying to implement jdbc Authentication. The problem is that I can't reach the backend via http. I have read that with following configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        ....
```

I can reach a default login page at my context application address. But I would like to call a `POST` login endpoint with `username` and `password` parameters.

How can I do this?

Comment: tip.... check where the default login page posts to....

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to receive the user credentials via a REST Endpoint and manually authenticate the user you can do this way:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    // constructor injecting authenticationManager

    @PostMapping
    public void login(@RequestBody UserCredentials credentials) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token
                = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword());

        Authentication auth = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(token);

        if (auth != null) {
            SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
            context.setAuthentication(auth);
            SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
        }

        throw new SomeException();
    }
}
```

This way, the `Filters` will take care of the rest of the authentication steps for you. The [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-securitycontextholder) can be researched for more details.

If you want to use the endpoint generated with the default login page, you can follow the steps from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-form) to make your own request:

- The form should perform a post to /login
- The form will need to
  include a CSRF Token which is automatically included by Thymeleaf.
- The form should specify the username in a parameter named username
- The form should specify the password in a parameter named password
- If the HTTP parameter error is found, it indicates the user failed to
  provide a valid username / password
- If the HTTP parameter logout is
  found, it indicates the user has logged out successfully

Comment: Thanks a lot, infact I do this way. But my goal was not to go through any controllers, exactly as it does when Thymeleaf or JSP are used. There are any example (with html login page) with no code at all except the security configuration. Thanks for your reply